# Melting and Freezing

Tags: water, energy, phase

Ok so I needed some help understanding one concept, for eg:- we are in an isolated room that has a room temperature of 0 degrees Celsius. And I bring in some water in the room, so eventually it will start freezing up at 0 degrees Celsius right?(doesn't matter the time), and when it's in an ice (solid) state its temperature is going to stay at 0 degree Celsius? if so then will it also not start melting if at 0 as the melting point of ice is also 0 degrees celsius, and as the room is 0 degrees celsius this will continue to loop?

Comment: As room is isolated at 0 °C, it cannot cause water freezing, as when it withdraws heat from water warmer than 0 °C it would warm itself  up above 0 °C. If water was 0 °C too, then there would be no heat exchange to freeze water.

Comment: thank you, but what if the room was big, big enough so that it wouldn't warm itself up entirely when cooling the water? so the water could use the cold temperature to cool itself? if possible, what would happen then?

Comment: If both room and water were 0 deg C then there would be no heat exchange, needed for phase transition, regardless of room size and heat capacity. If the room was colder than 0 deg C,then yes, water could freeze if room heat capacity was big enough.

Comment: what if water was let's assume 3 deg C, would it convert to ice? and as the melting point of ice is also 0 deg C would it then melt again? and it would continue to happen till the room was no longer 0 deg C?

Comment: Before asking, think, search and think again at least 1 hour.

Comment: alright will do

Comment: It'll never happen with you in the room.

Comment: "the room was big, big enough so that it wouldn't warm itself up" The function, for example, $1/x$ decays monotoneosly, yet never reaches or even crosses $0$. You cannot dilute the verdict "thermodynamically impossible" to the point where it suddenly becomes possible.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asserting an infinite, isothermal heat bath.  We use this construction in thermodynamics all the time.  Clearly what the poster means by "big enough" to have its temperature be unaffected by the introduction of water is an infinite isothermal heat bath.  He just doesn't know quite how to express it.  Rather than telling him why the way he's phrased  it won't work, why not be helpful and suggest a construct that would, and then address his question?

Comment: But the scenario is isolated, not closed isothermal system. Whatever big 0 °C bath would not take away heat from 0 °C water to freeze it. We could even combine this bath (if water) and the brought water into a single unit. Would it partially free, if isolated? It would not.

Comment: That's just the OP using the wrong words because they don't sufficiently understand thermodynamics to ask the question properly. The OP's intent is clearly for the room to stay at 0C: "...and as the room is 0 degrees celsius this will continue to loop?" The OP probably used "isolated" to mean "insulated", thinking that would keep it at 0C. So someone just needed to explain to the OP that, if they want the room to stay at 0C, it needs to be an infinite isothermal heat bath...

Comment: ....To use an analogy, suppose someone who didn't understand trucks went on an automotive site and asked how much gasoline a particular truck (that actually had a diesel engine) needs to go 100 km at 100 kph. What people should do is helpfully explain that this truck doesn't use gasoline, it uses diesel, and then give the fuel mileage. But if they acted like many of the answerers here, they would instead just unhelpfully say the question makes no sense because that model of truck uses diesel, not gasoline.

Answer (score 3):

No, the water wouldn't cycle in an infinite loop between liquid and ice.

Let's assume you introduced three different containers of water at $T=\pu {0 ^{\circ}C}$ and $\pu{p = 1 atm}$ into an infinite, constant-temperature heat bath, also at $T=\pu {0 ^{\circ}C}$ and $\pu{p = 1 atm}$ . These contain: (***a***) liquid water; (***b***) a 50-50 ice-water mixture; and (***c***) ice. Let's further assume the containers are diathermal, i.e., they allow the flow of heat.

In order for the liquid water in container ***a*** to turn to ice, heat would need to flow from that container to the bath. In order for the ice in container ***c*** to turn to liquid, heat would need to flow from the bath to that container. And the same applies to container ***b***: heat has to flow in to increase the proportion of water, and out to increase the proportion of ice.

According to classical thermodynamics, since they are all at $\pu {0 ^{\circ}C}$, there would be no heat flow between the water in the containers and the bath (no temperature difference means no heat flow). Thus they would all stay as they are.

However, statistically, I suppose it is possible you might have fluctuations that could cause changes. This is something I would need to think about further.

Comment: Sorry for asking the question with wrong words guys. I just hadn't reached the concepts of the thermodynamics stuff yet, so I didn't know about it. Absolutely sorry. But I figured theorist said that after the water was bought in the temperature of the water would go down to 0°C and then it would stop as they both have reached equilibrium. Thank you everyone for helping me out!

Comment: If ice and water are at equilibrium at zero Celsius the equilibrium is dynamic and the crystals and liquid and vapor will slowly redistribute about the enclosure. the relative amounts of each will not change unless energy is added to the mix.